# Vaadin ui components are incompatable

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have a view extended from `com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout`
I need to add a component `com.vaadin.ui.ListSelect`
But the `ListSelect` does not extend `Component`, so i can't use it on my view.

How can i arrange compatibility?

Comment: Which version of Vaadin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the ListSelect does not extend Component

ListSelect extends `com.vaadin.ui.Component`. Flow requires that your components extend `com.vaadin.flow.component.Component`.

Based on your package names `com.vaadin.ui` vs `com.vaadin.flow.component` it looks like you are mixing up Vaadin 8 and Vaadin 14+ for example (or Vaadin 7 and some other Vaadin 14+ version).

You may have the both frameworks in your classpath, thus IDE autocompletion suggest you classes from both libraries.

If you are developing application with Vaadin 14 or newer, instead of ListSelect component use `com.vaaadin.flow.component.select.Select`.

Comment: I found com.vaadin.flow.component.listbox.MultiSelectListBox. 
It's fine for me. Thanx =)